# "Call to a member function format() on bool"

Tags: laravel

I need to convert a decimal number to a time. In pure php it works perfect, but when you put it in the Laravel controller, I get this error:

> "Call to a member function format() on bool".

```
foreach($workdays as $hour){
    $num1 = $hour->hours_work.'m';
    $num_change1 = str_replace(',', 'h', $num1);
    $hour->hours_work = DateTime::createFromFormat('H\h i\m', $num_change1)->format('H:i');

    $num2 = $hour->hours_pause . 'm';
    $num_change2 = str_replace(',', 'h', $num2);
    $hour->hours_pause = DateTime::createFromFormat('H\h i\m', $num_change2)->format('H:i');
}
```

The entry would be 9.90

The departure should be 10:30

(This post has been translated via Google Translate)

Comment: share value of `$num_change1` ?

Comment: May be [this will](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a6905ab244b24fbbc3cc2dbefd32cad471098cd) help you

Comment: Post in english please, StackOverflow is international.

Comment: Sorry, i do not speak english. I will use Google translator.

Answer (score 1):

If `DateTime::createFromFormat` produces an error, the return value will be false (boolean)